# Spring Boot field not updating

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In my `User` class, I have this :

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<ClassRoom> classRooms  = new ArrayList<>();
```

And in my `ClassRoom` class, I have this :

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<User> admins = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now in my `UserController` class, I have :

```
@PostMapping("user/{id}/c")
User addClassRoom(@PathVariable Long id,@RequestBody ClassRoom newClassRoom)
{
    return repository.findById(id)
            .map(user -> {
                user.getClassRooms().add(newClassRoom);
                return repository.save(user);
            })
            .orElseGet(() -> {
                return null;
            });
}
```

And when I posted this **`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ }" http://localhost:8080/user/{id}/c`**

**`admins` filed of `User` is always `[]`**

Here is the snap :

[image: empty field spring boot in JSON]

And I have **4** tables related to this mapping:

[image: ManyToMany empty auto table spring boot]

I have tried **`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop`** in my *aplication.properties*

Empty tables :

- `CLASSROOM_ADMINS`
- `CLASSROOM_USER`
- `CLASS_ROOM_ADMINS`

Only table that holds the mapping :

- `USER_CLASS_ROOMS`

How can I resolve this ?

Here is all the table, related to `ManyToMany` mapping :

[image: tables related to many to many-spring boot]

Comment: Can you please note your ```datasource.url```? Is it file type?

Comment: I don't know what means your first picture. It is different url mapping with your ```UserController#addClassRoom```. If you would check your controller, please enter on your browser path to ```http://localhost:8080/user/1/c``` with request body parameter.

Comment: @윤현구 `datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/spring-boot-h2-db` and I don't understand the second comment

Comment: Can you post the DML for `USER_CLASS_ROOMS`, `USER` and `CLASSROOM` tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On `newClassRoom` you also need to add the existent `user` like this: `newClassRoom.getAdmins().add(user);`

**UPDATE**

I have fixed and committed, now should be working.

**What was wrong**

The stack overflow error was because of JSON serialization - it has nothing to do with JPA persistence - and it happened because `User` and `ClassRoom` have references to each other. To fix this, I marked the field `admins` with `@JsonIgnore` to break the circular reference.

---

Still the solution is not optimal because the user is obtained outside of a transaction boundary, therefore is in **detach** mode. Because of this, the `repository.save` method is forced to merge `user` into the persistence context. To avoid this overhead, I created a service with a transactional method to encapsulate everything (The second commit).

**BTW**

There are some code conventions in Java (like the package names are lower case etc). Please check [Google Java Style Code](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html)

Here is the `Service` :

```
/**
* @author Eugen Covaci {@literal eugen.covaci.q@gmail.com}
* Created on 10/8/2019
*/
@Service
public class UserService {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Transactional
public User addClassRoom(Long userId, ClassRoom newClassRoom) {
    return userRepository.findById(userId)
            .map(user -> {
                user.getClassRooms().add(newClassRoom);
                newClassRoom.getAdmins().add(user);
                return userRepository.save(user);
            })
            .orElseGet(() -> {
                return null;
            });
}
}
```

And in `Controller` use this :

```
return userService.addClassRoom(id, newClassRoom);
```

Comment: I'm sure that won't work, because that will create a loop... Shouldn't the `casscade` and `fetch` do this for me ?

Comment: Just try, it doesn't create a loop.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aMgGUiSkDm_lvVfXc6Fm16TGJmz11DD1/view?usp=sharing), I have tried already .

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad Not this way. You only have transaction on `repository.save` method, which means `user` is detached after find. Create a service class with a transactional method and put all the 3 lines of code within that clojure in that transactional method.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Service` class, can you help me out ?

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad It's a Java class annotated with `@Service`

Comment: Can simple write one , because I'm not familiar with that

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad Please make a simple proof-of-concept project on Github, I'll modify it there.

Comment: Give me your GitHub username, I will create as soon as I get back home

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad ecovaci

Comment: Invited , here is the [link](https://github.com/maifeeulasad/Spring-ManyToMany/invitations)